# a stop job is running for /nfs - server will not shut down

Tags: centos, nfs, systemd

I have an nfs mount on my base system, which, is targeted at a VM on that host. When shutting down the system, the VM went down first and and my base system was stuck trying to unmount the disk:

```
[ ***  ] A stop job is running for /nfs (3min 10s / 3min 31s)
[  *** ] A stop job is running for /nfs (3min 40s / 4min 11s)
[ ***  ] A stop job is running for /nfs (4min 43s / 5min 53s)
...
[ ***  ] A stop job is running for /nfs (15min 15s / 16min 2s)
```

I eventually had to kill the server externally because I had no control via SSH or the physical console. I will fix the mount issues on reboot, but,

---

How can I kill this process and continue with the system shutdown? What is the real timeout on waiting for a process if this timer is not actually showing anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the shutdown sequence to unmount network filesystem before stopping VM. For example by adding a custom targer that start last and stop first, like described [here](https://www.mauras.ch/systemd-run-it-last.html).